# Rejecting info from being stored in a file

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have a working program that searches Google using Mechanize, however when the program searches Google it also pulls sites that look something like `http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/`.

I would like to reject that site from being stored in the file. All the sites' URLs are structured differently.

Source code:

```
require 'mechanize'

PATH = Dir.pwd
SEARCH = "test"

def info(input)
  puts "[INFO]#{input}"
end

def get_urls
  info("Searching for sites.")
  agent = Mechanize.new
  page = agent.get('http://www.google.com/')
  google_form = page.form('f')
  google_form.q = "#{SEARCH}"
  url = agent.submit(google_form, google_form.buttons.first)
  url.links.each do |link|
    if link.href.to_s =~ /url.q/
      str = link.href.to_s
      str_list = str.split(%r{=|&}) 
      urls_to_log = str_list[1]
      success("Site found: #{urls_to_log}")
      File.open("#{PATH}/temp/sites.txt", "a+") {|s| s.puts("#{urls_to_log}")}
    end
  end
  info("Sites dumped into #{PATH}/temp/sites.txt")
end

get_urls
```

Text file:

```
http://www.speedtest.net/
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:M47_v0xF3m8J
http://www.speedtest.net/%252Btest%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
http://www.speedtest.net/results.php
http://www.speedtest.net/mobile/
http://www.speedtest.net/about.php
https://support.speedtest.net/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:R94CAo00wOYJ
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test%252Btest%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
https://www.test.com/
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:S92tylTr1V8J
https://www.test.com/%252Btest%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
https://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:sCEGhiP0qxEJ:https://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/%252Btest%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:WBvZnqZfQukJ:https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/%252Btest%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
http://www.humanmetrics.com/cgi-win/jtypes2.asp
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:w_lAt3mgXcoJ:http://www.humanmetrics.com/cgi-win/jtypes2.asp%252Btest%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
http://speedtest.xfinity.com/
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:snNGJxOQROIJ:http://speedtest.xfinity.com/%252Btest%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
https://www.act.org/content/act/en/products-and-services/the-act/taking-the-test.html
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:1sMSoJBXydo
https://www.act.org/content/act/en/products-and-services/the-act/taking-the-test.html%252Btest%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
https://www.16personalities.com/free-personality-test
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:SQzntHUEffkJ
https://www.16personalities.com/free-personality-test%252Btest%26gbv%3D%26%26ct%3Dclnk
https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:ypEu7XAFM8QJ:
https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud%252Btest%26gbv%3D1%26%26ct%3Dclnk
```

Comment: what about to add `if statement`, it should solve it too ?

Comment: And using a `skip` if the page matches webcache?

Comment: Yes, smth like this `(1..10).each{|a|
  next if a.even?
  puts a
}`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". When supplying data, reduce it to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything beyond that is visual clutter. Also, it appears you're using two different accounts with SO. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now. I had issue with `success('log')`, i dont know why but commented it.

```
  str_list = str.split(%r{=|&}) 
  next if str_list[1].split('/')[2] == "webcache.googleusercontent.com"
  # success("Site found: #{urls_to_log}")
  File.open("#{PATH}/temp/sites.txt", "a+") {|s| s.puts("#{urls_to_log}")}
```

Comment: That's a good answer, it works perfectly, I forgot to mention success is a method lol `def success(input)`;`puts "[SUCCESS]#{input}"`;`end`

Comment: I never know about `mechanize`. I thought the `success('log')` comes with `mechanize`. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are well-tested wheels used to tear apart URLs into the component parts so use them. Ruby comes with [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html), which allows us to easily extract the `host`, `path` or `query`:

```
require 'uri'

URL = 'http://foo.com/a/b/c?d=1'

URI.parse(URL).host
# => "foo.com"
URI.parse(URL).path
# => "/a/b/c"
URI.parse(URL).query
# => "d=1"
```

Ruby's [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html) module includes [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) and [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) which make it easy to loop over an array or enumerable object and reject or select elements from it:

```
(1..3).select{ |i| i.even? } # => [2]
(1..3).reject{ |i| i.even? } # => [1, 3]
```

Using all that you could check the host of a URL for sub-strings and reject any you don't want:

```
require 'uri'

%w[
  http://www.speedtest.net/
  http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fhl%3Den%26biw%26bih%26q%3Dcache:M47_v0xF3m8J
].reject{ |url| URI.parse(url).host[/googleusercontent\.com$/] }
# => ["http://www.speedtest.net/"]
```

Using these methods and techniques you can reject or select from an input file, or just peek into single URLs and choose to ignore or honor them.

Comment: I like to use more `URI` and `Nokogiri` but never know about `mechanize`.